# force "apply" to return a matrix?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data matrix and I want to first center the matrix by row and then calculate the mean by column.

```
a=matrix(runif(50),nrow=5)
a1=apply(a,1,function(x)x-mean(x))
a.sum=apply(a1,1,sum)
```

This works well when `a` has multiple columns. However, sometimes the input has only one column and that will cause trouble:

```
a=matrix(runif(5))
a1=apply(a,1,function(x)x-mean(x))
a.sum=apply(a1,1,sum)
Error in apply(a1, 1, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

This is because the first `apply` returned a vector, not a matrix. R automatically dropped the dimension. So is there a clever way to prevent this? I know I can use `if` to detective the dimension of `a` and process that with different coding. But that seems a bit awkward.

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind,apply(a, 1, function(x) list(x- mean(x))))` or `t(apply(a, 1, function(x) x- mean(x)))`

Comment: `a1` is just a vector of zeroes so not sure what are even trying to do. Though I would convert your whole process to `rowSums(scale(t(a), scale = FALSE))` in the first place. Or maybe just `colSums(a - rowMeans(a))`, both should work for your vector.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell R it's a matrix:

```
a=matrix(runif(5))
#          [,1]
#[1,] 0.0103764
#[2,] 0.9738857
#[3,] 0.2845688
#[4,] 0.7050949
#[5,] 0.3000554

a1=as.matrix(apply(a,1,function(x)x-mean(x)))
#     [,1]
#[1,]    0
#[2,]    0
#[3,]    0
#[4,]    0
#[5,]    0

a.sum=apply(a1,1,sum)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```